# Instantiating multiple modules in Verilog

Tags: indexing, verilog

I am writing an 8-bit register comprised of D ffs, and I was wondering if I there is an easier way I could instantiate it in a more simple and easier way, other than what I have below.

```
module multiplicand(
    input [7:0] A,
    output [7:0] RA,
    input reset,
    input LOAD_cmd,
     input clk
    );

d_flipflop ff0(.D(A[0]), .Q(RA[0]) , .reset(reset), .clk(clk) );
d_flipflop ff1(.D(A[1]), .Q(RA[1]) , .reset(reset), .clk(clk) );
d_flipflop ff2(.D(A[2]), .Q(RA[2]) , .reset(reset), .clk(clk) );
d_flipflop ff3(.D(A[3]), .Q(RA[3]) , .reset(reset), .clk(clk) );
d_flipflop ff4(.D(A[4]), .Q(RA[4]) , .reset(reset), .clk(clk) );
d_flipflop ff5(.D(A[5]), .Q(RA[5]) , .reset(reset), .clk(clk) );
d_flipflop ff6(.D(A[6]), .Q(RA[6]) , .reset(reset), .clk(clk) );
d_flipflop ff7(.D(A[7]), .Q(RA[7]) , .reset(reset), .clk(clk) );

endmodule
```

Ideally I want to create a vector ff[7:0] that contains all the instantiations above.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From Verilog-95 you can have a vector of instances:

```
d_flipflop ff[7:0] (A, Q, reset clk);
```

Were `A` and `Q` are vectors width matched to the number of instances.
My understanding is that since `reset` and `clk` are 1 bit the tools know to connect all instances to those 1 bit signals.